# API POST works, but I get a "No JSON object could be decoded"

Tags: python, json, oauth

I have an appliance that uses REST APIs to set/show information, and uses OAuth 2.0.

I have following Python code. The authentication works fine, but the POST commands are causing a crash.

```
import json
from sanction import Client

# The URL for access token requests
token_request_url = "https://192.168.42.5/oauth/token"

# Client name and secret
client_id = "test"
client_secret = "Paswordgoeshere"

# The base URL of the resource server
resource_base = "https://192.168.42.5/"

# Create the OAuth2 client object
client = Client(token_endpoint = token_request_url,
                resource_endpoint = resource_base,
                client_id = client_id,
                client_secret = client_secret)

# Request the access token into the client object
client.request_token(grant_type = 'client_credentials')

# Example GET request to show DNS servers
print "DNS Info"
print client.request('/rest/dns')
print ""
print ""
# Example POST request to PUT DNS servers
data = {"ip": "8.8.8.8"}
print json.dumps(data)

#data_json = json.dumps(data)

client.request('/rest/dns', data=json.dumps(data), headers={'content-type': 'application/json'})

#Crashing before the next line
print "New DNS Info"
print client.request('/rest/dns')
```

This works, the client.request line does add the DNS entry I need, but the line also crashes output:

```
python example.py   
DNS Info
[]


{"ip": "8.8.8.8"}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "example.py", line 36, in <module>
    client.request('/rest/dns', data=json.dumps(data), headers={'content-type': 'application/json'})
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sanction/__init__.py", line 170, in request
    'utf-8'))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 338, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 366, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 384, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

Comment: Try not calling json.dumps() on data like this: `client.request('/rest/dns', data=data, headers={'content-type': 'application/json'})`

Comment: @CodyBouche: it is the response that is being *decoded*, not the request data. The server responded with a non-JSON-decodable response.

Comment: The library doesn't offer much in the way of debugging; how comfortable are you with using `pdb` to step through the code and see what the response really contained?

Comment: Not very :) this is my first code in 10 years...

Comment: maybe the api response for POST is not a JSON object.  If you're up to it, you can create your own request function using the `requests` module that way you can see what the return value actually is.  Not sure if this client offers you the ability to do that.

Comment: Looking at sanction library you're using, you can pass `parser=lamba x: return x` to request, otherwise it defaults to json.loads.  https://github.com/demianbrecht/sanction/blob/master/sanction/__init__.py#L153

Comment: I'll see if I can reproduce with requests.  Had issues earlier getting requests to work with OAuth 2.0

Comment: @riotburn sorry, newbie here :)  how do I set this parser value?

Comment: @james `client.request(url, data=data, parser=parser)`